# Error in Gradsteyn and Ryzhik?

Tags: summation

I am looking in Gradsteyn and Ryzhik 7th edition and formula 0.241.11 is the following finite sum $$\sum_{k = 0}^i{\binom{i + k}{k}^{i - k}k} = (i + 1)4^i - (2i + 1)\binom{2i}{i}.$$ However, after looking at a few values of $i$ it appears that this equation is not correct. For example, for $i = 1$ we get $$\text{LHS} = \binom{1}{0}^1(0) + \binom{2}{1}^0(1) = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad \text{RHS} = (2)(4) - (3)\binom{2}{1} = 2.$$ Is this an error?

Comment: With how low the exponent $i - k$ is in the book, and how there's already a typo with an $h$ in the binomial coefficient in the formula there, it wouldn't surprise me if the exponent was supposed to be on the $k$ instead. For $i = 1$ it then works out, though I haven't looked further. Good catch though!

Comment: I thought that might be the case too, but that doesn't hold for $i = 2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128932/1104384, I was able to figure out a proof for the correct expression that Gonçalo gave!

From the post I linked (looking at the intermediate steps), one has: $$\tag{$*$}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}2^{n+1-k}k\binom{n+k}n = (n+1)\left(2^{2n+1}-\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\right)$$
Thus:
$$\begin{split} \sum_{k = 1}^n{\binom{n + k}{k}2^{n - k}k} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n{\binom{n + k}{k}2^{n+1 - k}k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n+1}{\binom{n + k}{k}2^{n+1 - k}k} - (n+1)\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\right)\\
&\overset{(*)}{=} \frac{1}{2}\left((n+1)\left(2^{2n+1}-\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\right)- (n+1)\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\right)\\
&= (n+1)4^n - (n+1)\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\\
&= (n+1)4^n - (2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}
\end{split}$$
which is the result we expected.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, the correct formula is
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^i{\binom{i + k}{k}2^{i - k}k} = (i + 1)4^i - (2i + 1)\binom{2i}{i}.
$$

Comment: Oh that makes sense with how it's formatted in the book, the low exponent was just an exponent tied to a number that didn't show up huh.

Comment: The expression you gave should be true, if I didn't do any mistake in my answer below.

Comment: Recognising the pattern was half the battle to be fair so your laziness wasn't in vain, wouldn't have done it without you ;)